# setting vue modal mask to blur

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to add a blur panel behind my modal using *vue.js* but **The problem** is that the `modal-mask` has the content nested in it so to add a `filter: blur()` property it'll blur everything.

Right now I can only add a black tint to the background.

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/EricTalv/2eed5qjo/26/

**HTML**

```
  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <ul id="flex-container">
        <li class="flex-item">
          <div id="list-area"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="flex-item">
          <div id="img-desc-container">
            <div class="image-area">
              <img src="http://dukes-lancaster.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/placeholder.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="description-area"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="modal-close" @click="$emit('close')">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

/* BLUR PANEL */

```
#modal-mask {
   position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    display: table;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll need to move the content into a separate container and toggle a blur class

https://jsfiddle.net/2eed5qjo/27/

```
<div :class="{'blur-content': showModal}">
  ... your content ...
</div>
<!-- use the modal component, pass in the prop -->
<modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
</modal>
```

then add a css class like this

```
.blur-content{
  filter: blur(5px); 
}
```